# good ways of adding/removing multiple directories to/from git repo?

Tags: git

Let's say I have this dir structure:

```
/project1
  /SomeFolder
  /obj
  /bin
/project2
  /obj
  /bin
```

Let's say each directory has source files I want to check in, but I don't want to check in /obj and /bin directories or their contents...

The way I did was

```
git add .
```

and than browse to each dir and do

```
git rm obj
git rm bin
```

As you can imagine this gets tedious especially if there are many directories... What is a better way to do something like that? Namely add multiple files with some exceptions, or remove all subdirectories with certain name?

update

to update multiple directories this will also work:

```
git rm */obj
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add these to the **.gitignore** file in the root of your git project:

```
echo obj >> .gitignore
echo bin >> .gitignore
```

Comment: that's nifty.. although those 2 commands put both directories on same line... trying

Comment: well they are on sep lines going in, but end up on same line in file.. i guess some kind of "/r/n" has to be echoed in as well ?

Comment: echo should always add a newline unless you suppress it with the -n option.

Answer (score 3):

You could just add [a .gitignore file](http://help.github.com/git-ignore/) for each project, right?

According to the docs:

> The git add command will not add
>   ignored files by default. If any
>   ignored files were explicitly
>   specified on the command line, git add
>   will fail with a list of ignored
>   files.